# Dimension of a Variety defined by the Weierstrass Equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, dimension-theory-algebra

I want to see why the following is true:

> A Variety described by the Weierstrass equation has dimension 1.

Let $K$ be a field. An **elliptic curve over $K$** is defined by the set of solutions in $\mathbb{P}^2(K)$ of a homogeneous **Weierstrass equation**
$$E: Y^2 Z + a_1 XYZ + a_3 YZ^2 = X^3 + a_2 X^2 Z + a_4 XZ^2 + a_6 Z^3$$ 
with $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\in K$. And we claim $E$ to be non-singular.

As definition of the dimension:

Let $V$ be an affine (projective) variety. We define the **dimension** $dim(V)$ as the biggest length $n$ of a chain $S_0\supset S_1 \supset \dots \supset S_n$ of distinct irreducible closed subspaces of $V$.

In Galbraith book Exercise 5.6.5 says:

> Let $f$ be a non-constant polynomial and let $X=V(f)$ be a variety in
>   $\mathbb{A}^n$. Show that $dim(X)=n-1$.

A proof for this is given in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" Proposition 1.13. But I don't understand all the algebra used for the proof:

> *Proof:* If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial, we have already seen that $Z(f)$ is a variety. Its ideal is the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(f)$. By "Krull's Hauptidealsatz" $\mathfrak{p}$ has height 1, so by 1.8A, $Z(f)$ has dimension $n-1$.
>   (*1.8A:* Let $k$ be a field, and let $B$ be an integral domain which is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then:
>   (a) the dimension of $B$ is equal to the transcendence degree of the quotient field $K(B)$ of $B$ over $k$;
>   (b)For any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $B$ we have
>   $$
> \operatorname{height}\mathfrak{p}+ \operatorname{dim} B/\mathfrak{p} = \operatorname{dim} B
> $$)

I don't understand the part (b) of the theorem 1.8A, what does the equation mean? What is $\operatorname{dim} B/\mathfrak{p}$, what does this notation mean?.
Maybe there is a  different approach to proof this Proposition?

I saw hints for this proof where they explain:

> Let $f\in k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n].$ Without loss of generality suppose $f$ contains at least one monomial featuring $x_n$. Then write $f=f_r x_{n}^{r}+f_{r-1}x_{n}^{r-1}+\dots + f_0$ with $f_i\in k[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$ or $k[x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}]$. One can check that the field $k(X)$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $k(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})$. [$k(X)$ field of fractions of $k[X]$ over $k$, where $k[X]=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_k(X)$] Finally, $k(X)$ is an algebraic extension of $k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

I would be really happy if someone could explain to me a little more detailed one of these proofs, or tell me another possible approach to prove this proposition.

Comment: (b) should read $B / \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: [Here are some good notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-11.pdf) by Andreas Gathmann.  Your Theorem 1.8A can be found on p. 98 as Lemma 11.6(b).

Comment: thanks Bubbles! and thanks also for the notes :)

Comment: Luca, I know that you are happy with Gathmann's notes (which are generally very good for a first read!) but let me make a comment that might be useful (or totally obvious). The 'reason' why this is true is that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is $2$-dimensional. In fact, if $E\subseteq\mathbb{P}^2$ denotes your elliptic curve, then a maximal chain of length $3$ (recall that it's the length of the chain minus $1$ for dimension!) is $\{[0:0:1]\}\subseteq E\subseteq\mathbb{P}^2$. So, now clearly $E$ is at least $1$-dimensional (consider the chain $\{[0:0:1]\}\subseteq E$) and if it were greater

Comment: say by a chain $\{[0:0:1\}\subseteq C\subseteq E$ then we'd get a chain o flength $4$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ showing it's dimension is $3$. This is semi non-rigorous (it's actually totally rigorous minus some minor details one can fix--well, assuming you know the dimension of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is $2$!) but it tells you `why' the result is true.

Comment: Thank you very much! It should have been totally obvious, but it was actually very useful :)

Comment: @Luca No problem :) Even less rigorously, but even more intuitive is that the dimension is the amount of parameters needed to describe a general point of the space. So, looking at the zero set $F=0$ eliminates one of these parameters by putting a non-trivial reliation between the parameters. Thus, $\dim V(f)$ is one less than the dimension of the ambient space. Of course, this is very non-rigorous (and not even true without some hypotheses) but is the right idea.